# Is it necessary to run activate command after activating virtual environment using pipenv shell command?

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, pipenv

As far as I know, for activating the virtual environment it's enought to just run `pipenv shell`

But in my case after running this command the parentheses at the beginning of the command prompt doesn't show up. Even after selecting the proper interpreter (the one inside venv folder)
[image]

To show the parentheses I should run `activate` command afterward.
[image]

So my question is: Is it important to show the project name in parentheses at the terminal prompt? Should I run the `activate` command after `pipenv shell` command every time?

I will appreciate if you describe the meaning of those parentheses. Tnx.

PS: I am using vscode in windows 10.

Comment: No.  It is just a prompt.  But if other environmental variables are being set than it is important and a clue that the environment may be wrong.  Normally when you log onto a machine the login setups the environment. Your pipe is not setting up the environment so the credentials may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to activate the environment manually. When you select the python interpreter and open the terminal, vscode will activate it automatically for you.

> The Python extension uses the selected environment for running Python code (using the Python: Run Python File in Terminal command), providing language services (auto-complete, syntax checking, linting, formatting, etc.) when you have a .py file open in the editor, and opening a terminal with the Terminal: Create New Terminal command. In the latter case, VS Code automatically activated the selected environment.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) for more details.

Comment: No, the problem is exactly about vscode doesn't activate it automatically even after selecting the proper interpreter(the one inside venv folder). check the first screenshot.

Comment: You can open a new terminal by **ctrl+shift+`** then run the python file.